# HOW-TO: use mod_rewrite to get rid of “?” in the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ojs

I already read in the forum about the problems related to mod_rewrite when we register in OAI, so I used this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?journal=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and also modified in "config.inc.php" and "config.TEMPLATE.inc.php" to

```
base_url[index] = http://www.ust.edu/ojs
base_url[myJournal] = http://www.ust.edu/ojs
restful_urls = on
```

But the result of that it deletes just "index.php" from URL and single question character "?" is still in the URL like " http://www.ust.edu/ojs/?journal=yjmp "which cause the problem.I want the URL to be like " http://www.ust.edu/ojs/ yjmp "
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "?journal=xxx" part of the URL indicates that you've got the path_info_disabled option turned "On" in your config.inc.php configuration file.

I'd suggest turning that option off, and ensuring that your web server is properly configured by testing it before adding any rewrite rules. Then try adding your rewrite configuration to the Apache setup.

Comment: thanks for replay .. i truned path_info_disabled to "off" but  htaccess file to rid only index.php and the question mark is still 
the url had become
"http://mysite/ojs/?journal=yjmp"
please help me i want to rid question mark from url for ojs 
thanks

Comment: If you still have ?journal=... appearing in your URLs and have turned off disable_path_info it's probably in one of your rewrite rules.

Comment: when i do disable_path_info is "off" the result was "No input file specified". and i do htaccess like RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/journal/$1 [R=301,L,NC] .. can U help me ? please

Comment: If OJS doesn't work with path_info_disabled=Off, then your server is not configured to work with PATH_INFO URLs. You'll need to change your Apache (or similar) and/or PHP configuration to support PATH_INFO URLs first.

Comment: thanks for reply 
... i know that .. so i made htaccess to configure Apache  to rid the question mark .. but it's not work .. the URL was still appear like "mysite/ojs/?journal=yjmp"; when i turn off the disable_path_info it show me  message  "No input file specified" .. please help